# Wordpress core function in custom hook

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, hook

I developed a plugin that sends a report by email with plugins to update. For this I use the function Wordpress [get_core_updates()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_core_updates/). Everything works with the hook admin_post_ when I do a manual sending.

My problem is that I want to send automatically with a CRON. When the event is triggered, I have an error:

- PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_core_updates()

The function is therefore not available when I go through a CRON event.

Do you have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `wp-admin/includes/update.php` available in the scope of your cron file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method belongs to `/wp-admin/includes/update.php` file, I guess this file won't be loaded in CRON mode since it's a part of the admin domain.

You can add this piece of code in your CRON function:

```
if (false === function_exists('get_core_updates')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/update.php');
}
```

It will include the file with the function. I would think this access can lead to some security issues.